# Adding Angular App or component to preexisting webpage

Tags: html, angular

I have been tasked to add functionality to a pretty big webpage.
This functionality would take quite long to realize in plain old js, but is actually quite easy and fast to do in Angular 5. Or so i thought.

The question i can't seem to find via google: Can i actually create an angular 5 project, with all the functionality i need, build it... and then plug it into an pre existing webpage?

If so, are there any ressources / tutorials that show this?

All i can dig up are great tutorials on how to build a web page with Angular, but that is not possible for my task. The pre existing web page is used by 100s of different teams, so i can't just redo it, i can only add something.

I am asking this because id rather not build and app and then fail at implementing it. I have full freedom of HOW i do it, as long as i can just do some plug and play magic once i am done.

Comment: I think its still experimental, but check out "angular elements".

Comment: I could be wrong here, but I don't think angular was designed for this. I believe Reactjs would be a better fit.

Comment: So you would say learning to do this in react would be easier? All i have to do is make some database data sortable and show it filtered on the page. Really nothing major, i hope. React is a good fit for this task?